# Time optimization with C? In a simple input reading algorithm

Tags: c, optimization, time

I'm reading a file with a set format so I'm sort of aware of what to expect from the file, however, when I try to print all the input, just to make sure that the code works, the console crashes with a timeout exception. I've got a nested for loop, since I find it the easiest way to handle the file format. But I don't know if there's a better way to handle this.

The problem is a geeks for geeks coding challenge. I noticed that when I change the for variable use in the for loop the code compiles, but this way I wouldn't be able to handle different file formats. As long as I have a constant in the for loop as my parameter it runs. Any idea as to why that is?

the first line is the number of cases, every first line after that tells me the number of node and the number of links, and the following line has linking nodes.

The expected output would be 4 and 3 but I haven't made it that far yet, I'm still making sure that I'm able to read in file properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int nextInt();
int main() {
    int c = getchar() - '0';
    printf("%d\n", c);
    while(c > 0){
        int x, y;
        x = nextInt();
        y = nextInt();
        printf("%d%4d\n", x, y);
        int i, a, b;
        for(i = 0;i<2*y; i++){
            a = nextInt();
            printf("%4d", a);
        }
        printf("\n");
        c--;
    }
    return 0;
}

int nextInt(){
    int c, n;
    int num;
    while(isspace(c=getchar())){;}
    num = c - '0';
    while(!isspace(n = getchar())){
        num = (num * 10) + (n - '0');
    }
    return num;
}
```

An example for the input looks something like this:

```
2
4 4 
0 2 0 3 1 3 2 3
4 3 
0 2 0 1 0 3
```

output

```
4
3
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with optimization. You need to use the debugger to find out why your code is not functioning properly. Once it's working and producing the correct output, you can start looking at optimizing it when you identify a specific bottleneck. It's not optimization when you're trying to get code to actually work - that's called debugging.

Comment: Most likely you're going into an infinite loop.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you've written your own code to parse numbers, instead of using `scanf()`?

Comment: How are you running your code? It looks like it should read at least your sample file correctly.  Even though you don't handle many error conditions, like @Barmar mentions

Comment: @bruceg If the last line doesn't end with a newline, it will go into an infinite loop looking for a whitespace character to end the last number.

Comment: its a logic error

Comment: the while(isspace(c=getchar())) { ;} would make it not run, there is nothing in that loop and no way to get out of it that i can see

Comment: @Parkofadown It gets out of the loop when `getchar()` returns a non-whitespace character.

Comment: You can have { ;} and it doesn't throw an error ? I had also thought that you would have to cast an int to a char since they are declared as an int.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop in `nextInt()` doesn't stop when it reads EOF. If the last line doesn't end with a newline, you'll go into an infinite loop, because it will never find the delimiter after the last number.

```
int nextInt(){
    int c, n;
    int num;
    while(isspace(c=getchar())){;}
    num = c - '0';
    while(!isspace(n = getchar()) && n != EOF){
        num = (num * 10) + (n - '0');
    }
    return num;
}
```